# Python Pandas: Fill value from one dataframe with the value from a second dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a list of records that have a report date associated with them.  I need to associate these records with a month based on an in-house calendar.  This in-house calendar is held in a different dataframe.  The in-house calendar is not based on standard months.

My goal is to check the dates of the report in my dataframe of record and see if they fall within the calendar range in df_cal.  If they do, I would like to return the in-house month from df_cal and attach it to the appropriate record in df1.

I've tried just about everything that I can think of including attempting to nest an apply method within another apply method but couldn't figure out how to get it to work.  The latest route I tried was pairing apply with where.  I know this method won't work either but I've stripped it down and included it to show the logic needed to transfer the month.  I can't seem to figure this one out.

About the real data:
In reality, df1 is thousands of rows long and the calendar dataframe is 48 rows (4 years) for the time being; however, the dataframes below represent the major points of friction I am encountering with this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Calendar Dataframe:**

```
d_c = {"Month": ["May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep"],
       "FY": [2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
       "Start Date": ["4/27/2020", "5/25/2020", "6/22/2020", "7/27/2020", "8/24/2020"],
       "End Date": ["5/24/2020", "6/21/2020","7/26/2020", "8/23/2020", "9/20/2020"]}

dfc = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dfc["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfc["Start Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
dfc["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfc["End Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

**Report Dataframe:**

```
d_1 = {"Report Date":["5/5/2020","5/26/2020","6/9/2020",
                      "6/30/2020","7/14/2020","8/11/2020",
                      "8/25/2020","9/8/2020","9/15/2020"],
       "FY": [2020, 2021, 2021,
              2021, 2021, 2021,
              2021, 2021, 2021],
       "Name": ["Jamaal","Tamba","Patrick",
                "Tony","Derrick","Trent",
                "Clyde","Chris","Priest"
               ]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d_1)
df1["Report Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Report Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

**Attempted Solution:**

```
def conditions(df_row):
    '''Passed to apply() to add correct months
    to the report.  This function specifies the conditions under which the
    month will be returned.'''
    
    report_fy = df_row["FY"]
    report_date = df_row["Report Date"]
    calendar_fy = dfc["FY"]
    month_start = dfc["Start Date"]
    month_end = dfc["End Date"]
    month = dfc["Month"]
    
    # This doesn't work, but it does show the logic that I need.
    return np.where((report_fy == calendar_fy)
                    & (report_date >= month_start)
                    & (report_date <= month_end))

df_out = df1.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    Report Date  FY     Name    Month
0   2020-05-05   2020   Jamaal  May
1   2020-05-26   2021   Tamba   Jun
2   2020-06-09   2021   Patrick Jun
3   2020-06-30   2021   Tony    Jul
4   2020-07-14   2021   Derrick Jul
5   2020-08-11   2021   Trent   Aug
6   2020-08-25   2021   Clyde   Sep
7   2020-09-08   2021   Chris   Sep
8   2020-09-15   2021   Priest  Sep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `np.where` you can filter months and if match return first matched value:

```
def conditions(df_row):
    '''Used as part of the flex_relay_month function to apply the correct Relay month
    to the FLEX and PDR report.  This function specifies the conditions under which the
    Relay month will be returned.'''
    
    report_fy = df_row["FY"]
    report_date = df_row["Report Date"]
    calendar_fy = dfc["FY"]
    month_start = dfc["Start Date"]
    month_end = dfc["End Date"]
    month = dfc["Month"]
    
    # This doesn't work, but it does show the logic that I need.
    out = month[((report_fy == calendar_fy)
                    & (report_date >= month_start)
                    & (report_date <= month_end))].to_numpy()
    return out[0] if len(out) > 0 else ''

df1['Month'] = df1.apply(conditions, axis=1)

print (df1)
  Report Date    FY     Name Month
0  2020-05-05  2020   Jamaal   May
1  2020-05-26  2021    Tamba   Jun
2  2020-06-09  2021  Patrick   Jun
3  2020-06-30  2021     Tony   Jul
4  2020-07-14  2021  Derrick   Jul
5  2020-08-11  2021    Trent   Aug
6  2020-08-25  2021    Clyde   Sep
7  2020-09-08  2021    Chris   Sep
8  2020-09-15  2021   Priest   Sep
```

Another idea is merge together and then filter:

```
df = df1.merge(dfc, on='FY')


df = df.loc[df["Report Date"].between(df["Start Date"], df["End Date"]),
            df1.columns.tolist() + ['Month']]
print (df)
   Report Date    FY     Name Month
0   2020-05-05  2020   Jamaal   May
1   2020-05-26  2021    Tamba   Jun
5   2020-06-09  2021  Patrick   Jun
10  2020-06-30  2021     Tony   Jul
14  2020-07-14  2021  Derrick   Jul
19  2020-08-11  2021    Trent   Aug
24  2020-08-25  2021    Clyde   Sep
28  2020-09-08  2021    Chris   Sep
32  2020-09-15  2021   Priest   Sep
```